# Monitoring current status of the Diablo III servers?

Tags: diablo-iii

Blizzard has a page for [*Diablo III* server status](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/status), but it doesn't seem to be wholly accurate; I'm currently getting an "outage of Battle.net" error.  If Battle.net is a distinct hoop I need to jump through when logging in, is its status available elsewhere?  If not a simple red-light/green-light indicator; is there a forum for official announcements that's not flooded by plebeians?

Is there some 3rd party "are the servers up" website (e.g. EVE)?

Comment: Just to strengthen your point: I was able to log in and play just fine even when that page indicated my server is down. So it seems to be inaccurate both ways.

Answer (score 10):

At the moment your best bet is to follow Blizzard's Twitter updates at https://twitter.com/#!/BlizzardCS.  They've kept regular updates on Diablo III server availability, including the current maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

[GamePlayStatus](http://www.gameplaystatus.com) is also useful for checking overall status.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a website, but a small application that shows the server status for those on Android -

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mastaphora.diabloserverstatus

Answer (score 0):

The [Diablo 3 subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/diablo) has an area on the sidebar that reports the status of all the servers and the last time they were checked.

[image]

In my experience, it has been very up-to-date, closely following downtimes on all three servers.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is install this extension for Google Chrome: [Diablo Server Status Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mpiocogpenlopnoeibcegpepnoggijck).

This extension allows you to know what the status of the Diablo 3 servers is with a popup or notification. It also allows you to see the status of the auction house. You can also set the frequency (in minutes) that the extension verifies the status of the server.

Comment: There are also small apps that monitor Blizzard's status feed. [One of them is for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.eluamous.d3serverstatus)

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  The extension is just reading the feed, which the author claims, is not accurate.  How is this an answer to the question?